# How to alter the duration of a Tokio timer stream that has been combined with another stream?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have three streams:

1. a timer stream (defined below)
2. a broadcast channel stream (defined below)
3. a WebSocket stream (not defined here but I don't think it's necessary. It's based on tokio-tungstenite)

I join these 3 streams together with a `select`.

I want commands I send down the broadcast channel to alter the timer - I want to be able to re-adjust the tokio timer once the streams are fused together.

This is my timer stream:

```
fn timer_stream(dur: u64) -> impl futures::stream::Stream<Item = Input> {
    let task_time = tokio::time::Instant::now();

    tokio::time::interval_at(task_time, Duration::from_secs(dur))
        .map(move |_| Input::Command_first(task_time))
}
```

I want to be able to change the `task_time` and the `dur`.

This is how I combine my streams together:

```
let mut websocket_timer = select(exchange_websocket_stream, timer_stream(3));
let mut combined = select(websocket_timer, command_receiver);
```

`command_receiver` is defined with use `tokio::sync::broadcast;` like so:

```
let (tx_tcp_commands, mut rx_tcp_commands) = broadcast::channel::<Input>(16);
command_receiver = tx_tcp_commands.subscribe()
```

`Input` is:

```
enum Input {
    Command_second(tokio::time::Instant),
    Command_first(tokio::time::Instant),
    Thing,
}
```

I then put the above in a `tokio::main` executor and do

```
loop {
    match combined.next().await {
        None => break,
        Some(Input::Command(t)) => etc,
    }
}
```

This works as a general stream and I can match on commands sent down to `command_receiver`, I just need to know how to change the timer parameters.

The loop is processing a very high amount of WebSocket messages so it has to be efficient.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work with the code as-is. I might suggest a redesign. Instead of a single stream, create a task with an MPSC channel. This task yields the same result of your current stream, but also listens on the input side of the channel for updates to the time.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!